# Passing hierarchy context to agenda items in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

The org-mode Agenda from the following org-mode file:

```
* TODO Presentation on Important Project
** TODO Meeting
        DEADLINE: <2011-09-05 Mon>
** TODO Presenting to group
        DEADLINE: <2011-09-06 Tue>
```

will show "Meeting" and "Presenting to group" on the appropriate days, but without the context of the main headline (Presentation on Important Project). Therefore, all context is lost and "Meeting" on 2011-09-05 means nothing. The workaround is to do the following:

```
* TODO Presentation on Important Project
** TODO Meeting about the Presentation on Important Project
        DEADLINE: <2011-09-05 Mon>
** TODO Presenting to group about the Presentation on Important Project
        DEADLINE: <2011-09-06 Tue>
```

which seems too complicated and requires duplication of the first headline. Is there an alternative method or a way to show the context/hierarchy in the agenda. I have previously found references to various variables dealing with hierarchies in org-mode, but these relate to sparse trees, not the agenda view. This discussion [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/15735/focus=15739) appears to address this issue, but no solution is provided.

After further searching, I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807259/org-mode-agenda-tree-view) question here. [The accepted answer involves right-clicking entries, which is not possible for me as I use org-mode on a headless server over SSH.]

Comment: With the pointer on an agenda entry, the mini-buffer will show the context for that entry. I still need to check if there is a setting for this.

Comment: Oh yes, I've noticed that before but forgot about it. It's a reasonable alternative if there is no other solution. Thanks.

Comment: Could you use tags or a property on the parent headline to mark what it relates to? Both are discussed in the mailing list you linked as a preliminary solution that was not applicable for the user due to their requirements.

Comment: @Juancho do you know of the minibuffer setting? I used to see the context hierarchy there, but it is no longer, and I found it useful...

Comment: I use properties and org-icons for that, they do a lovely job, also they make my agenda cute.