# Is it possible to get org-mode to show breadcrumbs in agenda todo list?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, todo

In Emacs, I have a set of TODOs in the following format

```
* H1
** H2
*** H3
**** TODO X
```

When I look at the agenda-todo view, it shows up only as `TODO x`. Is there any way to get the agenda view to display it as `H1/H2/H3/TODO X` ?

Comment: The breadcrumb for the item under the pointer appears in the minibuffer. Not what you ask for, but maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it is useful, but I would really like to see breadcrumbs for all pending tasks at once.

Comment: Here is a link to the same feature request on the mailing list from a couple of years ago -- it contains some ideas (with code) on how to implement this feature:  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/60873

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the feature being discussed is what Juancho has mentioned (showing the breadcrumbs one at a time).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this solution from [here](http://blog.ryuslash.org/archives/2012/12/19/orgagendaprefixformat)

```
(setq org-agenda-prefix-format '((agenda . " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s")
         (timeline . "  % s")
         (todo .
               " %i %-12:c %(concat \"[ \"(org-format-outline-path (org-get-outline-path)) \" ]\") ")
         (tags .
               " %i %-12:c %(concat \"[ \"(org-format-outline-path (org-get-outline-path)) \" ]\") ")
         (search . " %i %-12:c"))
      )
```

This shows the breadcrumbs in the agenda todo view.

Comment: IMO you should just use `%b` directly to display the breadcrumb.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use `%b` in the format string to show the breadcrumb.

Comment: Yes, you can use `%b`, which renders the breadcrumbs using `->` as the separator. `(org-format-outline-path (org-get-outline-path))` on the other hand renders it using `/` as the separator. I personally find the latter more readable, and hence prefer @rahul solution. Totally a matter of taste though...

Comment: You can set a custom separator to be used with `%b` via the `org-agenda-breadcrumbs-separator` variable