# Extract the second level headline

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, org-mode, spacemacs

For my global TODO list, I am showing breadcrumbs as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888785/is-it-possible-to-get-org-mode-to-show-breadcrumbs-in-agenda-todo-list) :

```
(concat \"[ \"(org-format-outline-path (org-get-outline-path)) \" ]\") ")
```

to produce following:

[image]

[image]

I would like to show only the second level of project breadcrumb. So in this case, I would only display `[Project A]`. I think if I can make a function that can extract the second level, I just need to prepend with `%?` so that `[Tasks]` does not appear for Tasks, but only project names would appear for Projects. What would be an ideal way of extracting the second level?

Comment: How do you make main ORG headers look as on the picture?

Comment: @mobiuseng Not sure what you are asking, but I am using [spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/), so I haven't configured the design aspect myself.

Comment: @mobiuseng The bullets come from [org-bullets](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do to get the second element of `(org-get-outline-path)` is to call `nth`.

> (nth N LIST)
>
> Return the Nth element of LIST.
>   N counts from zero.  If LIST is not that long, nil is returned.

The second element is `(nth 1 LIST)`.  Replace `(org-get-outline-path)` with `(list (nth 1 (org-get-outline-path)))` (we use `list` because that's what `org-format-outline-path` expects).

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked out well. However, I still have one problem that I cannot figure out for some reason. Could you take a look at the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910204/org-agenda-prefix-format-does-not-work)?